# Extend a 3rd party module via theme

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, frontend

Simple question, would it be possible to overwrite the templates in a 3rd party theme via the active theme?

I.e. if I have

`/app/code/Vendor/SomeModule/view/frontend/templates/structure.phtml`

would I be able to overwrite it via

`/app/design/frontend/Me/MyTheme/Vendor_SomeModule/templates/structure.phtml`

In the same way we could overwrite Magento_Modules?

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** You can override at that way into design theme.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Namespace_Modulename/templates
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't do anything. The module path is `/app/code/Magefan/Blog/view/frontend/templates/post/list.phtml`, so the correct path in my theme would be `/app/design/frontend/My/Theme/Magefan_Blog/templates/post/list.phtml` right? I've cleaned cache and all, it's not being read.

Comment: Yes, Its correct path, I have also override same module file in my custom theme. Its working fine. May be o\your content are coming from different files. please check it. Also remove var folder.

Comment: i think your theme, My/Theme or My/MyTheme check your theme path.

Comment: You're right :) Made a typo, this is working fine!